# MyISAM - SELECT * FROM table WHERE t > ... not using key for t

Tags: mysql, select, indexing, myisam

I have a a database where events are stored with a timestamp, which is pretty huge. The database uses 3 keys, one of them is the timestamp "t".

Table Definition:

`id      | bigint(20) AI PK
 id_para | int(10) UN
 t       | int(11) UN
 t_ms    | smallint(6) UN
 t_ns    | bigint(20) UN PK
 id_inst | smallint(6)
 value   | varchar(255)
 isanchor| tinyint(4) UN`

As mentioned, the Engine is MyISAM, I'm working with mysql5.6.

When i want to get every event after a certain timestamp, i use

```
SELECT * FROM edl.data_inc WHERE t > '1424685000';
```

Explain states it checks about 400k rows and uses where. It should use the index though, as it does with

```
SELECT t FROM edl.data_inc WHERE t > '1424685000';
```

Explain shows it checks about 100k rows and uses where and index. The only way i get the DB to use the index for a SELECT * is with

```
SELECT * FROM edl.data_inc FORCE INDEX(t) WHERE t > '1424685000';
```

Even then it does not say using index, but the rows count is only 100k aswell. Altering the timestamp to a number and not a string does not do anything aswell.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's best when asking questions about database performance to include your table definition in your question. Please edit your question to show that.

Comment: Have you tried `ANALYZE TABLE edl.data_inc` and then retrying your query? Sometimes the statistics used by the query planner are out of date so it concludes that a full table scan is faster than an index scan followed by a series of table lookups.

Comment: Compare the execution speed when a full table scan is performed, then clear your query cache, measure the query again with forced index. MySQL  won't use an index if it determines that full table scan is faster. This is done when indexes have low(er) cardinality.

Comment: I included the definition, i hope that's what you asked for? After `ANALZYE TABLE edl.data_inc` nothing changes.

Comment: Just dummy question: table structure has timestamp on `t_ns`; but all your SQL queries refer to `t`, which in INT. Sure you check correct field? (sorry, if its dummy) :)

Comment: @N.B. Sorry to ask, but what is a full table scan?

Comment: @cyadvert i'm checking the right field, yes. `t_ns` is a column for joining with another table

Comment: Full table scan is when MySQL reads the entire table instead of using an index to read part of the table. It's basically the worst case scenario.